# Create Bean and Name using @Bean annotation and Spring EL Expressions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I try to create a Bean and its name using `@Bean(value="")` attribute. The `value` should be set with `Spring EL Expression`.

```
@Configuration
public class TestClass{

   @Autowired
   TestProperty testProperty

   @Bean(value="#{testProperty.name}")
   public MyBean myBean(){
       MyBean b = new MyBean();
       return b;
   }
}
```

My `testProperty` is correct injected and holds a value for example `testProperty.name = "Bean1"`

At the moment my created Bean just have the EL expression as its name: `{"bean":"#{testProperty.name}"`

**How can I give `MyBean` its name from `testProperty.name`?**

Comment: I really doubt you can do use SpEL or bean names. Can you elaborate on your use case?

Comment: @luboskrnac My use case is that I have to create quartz jobs configured outside in a property file. So it can be one or more jobs. There is [another open question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022276/how-to-create-spring-beans-in-a-dynamical-way-using-quartz-schedulerfactorybean) regarding this issue from me. Maybe this can give you the context.

Comment: I have replied a very similar question of yours regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929161/spring-boot-one-scheduled-task-using-multiple-cron-expressions-from-yaml-file/40930043#40930043

Answer (score 1):

You can use property value for `cron` attribute of `@Scheduled` annotation:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${testProperty.name}")
```

So no need for SpEL at all.